# Issues in integrating ffmpeg with omxil

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to make media player based on OMX IL.I want to use ffmpeg as demuxer.Is there any sample code that shows how to integrate ffmpeg with omxil.Basically i want to give AVFormatContext packets as input to omxil decoder.

Please point me to any docs/sample code.

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

Today [libstagefright.cpp](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavcodec/libstagefright.cpp;h=346cc9ce607e7e00d1b776ddfc954cdbaca97484;hb=HEAD) is part of the official ffmpeg source. You can see it as an example, if you want to write your wrapper.

Comment: If you can point to any example player that uses ffmpeg and omxil to play a/v file.I will base my player over that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a google that will scan private projects of other people. What it does find, is the price tag for your request: [avg. €583](http://www.freelancer.com/projects/Mobile-Phone-Android/Android-video-player-ffmpeg.html).